# How to consume a WCF service returning JSON value in MVC application?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am consuming a WCF web service in that, having list of employee details and the result of WCF is returning from JSON. I want to consume that in my MVC application.

How can I consume that list of employee details in my MVC application? Please can anyone help me (I am very new to MVC)?

Thanks in advance.

```
public string Employee_SelectDetails() { 
using (ISession session=nHibernateHelperClass.nHibernateHelperClass.OpenSession())
 {// Retrieving a value from sql using nHibernate 
var users = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Empdetails)).List(); 
// Using JSON to pass serialize data to front end(MVC) System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer objJSSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); 
string strJSON = objJSSerializer.Serialize(users); 
return strJSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the Ajax call to the hosted WCF function . On Success method of AJAX call , you can parse the result to string or any format

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to consume the service in the server side code or from client side?

Comment: from client side  . my server side code is like this(WCF)                  public string Employee_SelectDetails()
        { using (ISession session=nHibernateHelperClass.nHibernateHelperClass.OpenSession())  {// Reteriving a value from sql using nHibernate var users = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Empdetails)).List();
                // Using JSON to pass seriliza data to front end(MVC) 
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer objJSSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); string strJSON = objJSSerializer.Serialize(users); return strJSON;

Comment: If you're using jQuery, just make a call to the method Employee_SelectDetails, that must be an Action in some Controller, just like this:

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/NameOfController/Employee_SelectDetails/",
 dataType: "json",
    success: function(retorno){
        alert(retorno);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});